# How to export a variable to all of the stages in CICD?

Tags: gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, cicd

I have some stages and I need to create a name for a folder in one stage and use it in another stage. like the code below :

```
  ...
  before_script:
    - cd publish
    - export TZ=Europe/Madrid
    - ln -snf /usr/share/zoneinfo/$TZ /etc/localtime && echo $TZ > /etc/timezone
    - export BACKUP_FOLDER_NAME=$(date +%Y%m%d.%H%M)
  ...
```

and now I want to create a folder in another stage and name it the date in BACKUP_FOLDER_NAME.
How to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `dotenv` report artifacts to pass variables to subsequent stages/jobs via artifacts

```yaml
set-variables:
  stage: .pre # always the first stage in a pipeline
  script:
    # ... set your variables
    # create the dotenv file
    - echo "BACKUP_FOLDER_NAME=${BACKUP_FOLDER_NAME}" > vars.env
  artifacts:
    reports:
      dotenv: "vars.env"

build:
  stage: build
  script:
    # this variable was set automatically by the artifact
    - echo "$BACKUP_FOLDER_NAME"
# ...
```

---

However, if you just want a common time for all jobs in a pipeline to use, you can use the predefined variable `$CI_PIPELINE_CREATED_AT` which is an ISO8601 timestamp of the pipeline creation time (e.g., `2023-07-17T17:11:20Z`).

```yaml
before_script:
  # in case your image doesn't have tzdata configured use this step:
  - DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt update && apt install -y tzdata
  # use $CI_PIPELINE_CREATED_AT to form the backup folder name:
  - BACKUP_FOLDER_NAME=$(TZ='Europe/Madrid' date -d "$CI_PIPELINE_CREATED_AT" +%Y%m%d.%H%M)
  - echo "backup folder is ${BACKUP_FOLDER_NAME}"
```

In this case, you won't have to pass any variables between jobs because `CI_PIPELINE_CREATED_AT` is the same value for all jobs in the same pipeline.